# Mapbox Application crashes while launching

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am trying to create a simple mapbox application which shows a mapview. There is no specific error shown while debugging but the application crashes while launching itself.Here is the .java file which I created.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MapView mapView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Mapbox.getInstance(this,String.valueOf(R.string.access_token));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}
}
```

Here is my .xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.logusubramaniyan.choropleth1.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTilt="20"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="12"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't understand why the activity fails to launch when run on either emulator or any device.Any ideas?

Here is my StackTrace result.

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                          Process: com.example.logusubramaniyan.choropleth1, PID: 17191
                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.logusubramaniyan.choropleth1/com.example.logusubramaniyan.choropleth1.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Comment: Show us your stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: post logcat please .

Comment: read https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/

Comment: use directly map activity don't use other map view.

Comment: I have followed completely as said in the above link. mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk . Still there is some other issue because of which the app is crashing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`String.valueOf()` doesn't properly convert it to a string value,hence not properly reading the access token.

Try pasting the access token directly instead of giving it is R.string.something.

Your problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try  putting this line

```
 Mapbox.getInstance(this,String.valueOf(R.string.access_token));
```

after setContentView line and check.

Comment: I checked and its still crashing without even launching.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding access token to view in layout like that:
`mapbox:access_token="access_token"`

Comment: It did not recognize anything like that in layout file.

Comment: sorry, also add `xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: I have already added that too. Still while running, it showed error. This is the error -:No resource identifier found for attribute 'access_token' in package 'com.example.logusubramaniyan.choropleth1'

Comment: @AadhilAhmed you sure you're running latest mapbox? 1.1.0?

Comment: compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.1.3@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }    I have added this package but I am not sure if it is the latest.

Answer (score 0):

To support @aadhil's answer,

Try to adjust this line

```java
String.valueOf(R.string.access_token)
```

to

```java
this.getResources().getString(R.string.access_token)
```